# Код сервера 302 вместо 200 как исправить?

Tags: php, java, html

```
$domain = 'chat.asidneff.ru';

if(in_array($_GET['theme'], array('index.php', 'standard'))){
    switchVersionSite($domain, $_GET['theme']);
}else if(empty($_COOKIE['theme'])){
    $theme = 'standard';
    if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) || preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],0,4))){
        $theme = 'mobile';
    }
    switchVersionSite($domain, $theme);
}

function switchVersionSite($domain, $theme){
    setcookie ('theme', $theme, time() + 864000, '/', $domain, 0);
    if($theme == 'mobile'){
        $domain = 'm' . $domain.'';
    }
    header('Location: https://' . $domain.'/');
}
```

Яндекс говорит, что сервер отдаёт 302 с этим кодом, а нужно 200.
Как можно исправить, чтоб и переадресация осталась, и код поменялся на 200?

Comment: Ну так ты же сам делаешь редирект. Не делай редирект.

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня стоит полная и мобильная версия.... Как тогда перенаправлять людей на мобильную?

Comment: Тебе нужно с помощью js или php выявлять на чем сидит юзер. Вроде user-agent можно проверять, но это не точно. Вот ссылка полезная: https://www.cyberforum.ru/php-beginners/thread356505.html

Comment: По юзер агенту определяешь клиента и решаешь как поступить. У ботов поисковиков тоже свои ЮА. Это стандартный способ

Answer (score 0):

Дак изначально всё дело на PHP... Вот интересно, что на счёт JS, там же тоже редирект будет?!
В примере с Киберфорума определяется агент, как и у меня.

```
function check_smartphone() {

 $phone_array = array('iphone', 'android', 'pocket', 'palm', 'windows ce', 'windowsce', 'cellphone', 'opera mobi', 'ipod', 'small', 'sharp', 'sonyericsson', 'symbian', 'opera mini', 'nokia', 'htc_', 'samsung', 'motorola', 'smartphone', 'blackberry', 'playstation portable', 'tablet browser');
        $agent = strtolower( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );
     
        foreach ($phone_array as $value) {
     
            if ( strpos($agent, $value) !== false ) return true;
     
        }
     
        return false;
     
    }
```

А что дальше с ним делать? Как отправить на поддомен мобильной, если яндекс видит это перенаправление?